# Sending large files over MQTT / mosquitto - limit at 4MB

Tags: c, mqtt, mosquitto

My goal is to be able to send a file of around 150MB over `mosquitto`. The matters of efficiency of such transfer are not important at the moment, it's just to find out if such a transfer is possible.

MQTT specification mentions a message payload limit of 256MB, however I was only able to send a file of size up to 4095KB and nothing more. The publisher is implemented with C mosquitto library, dynamically allocating a vector with binary data. The publisher program does not run into any errors, however after the data is published on the client side, no notifications of publishing are present on the broker side if the sent file is larger than 4065KB, nor the `mosquitto_sub` receives any messages, what happens though is a message from the broker that the publishing client disconnected with success:

```bash
1711360340: New connection from 127.0.0.1:50002 on port 1883.
1711360340: New client connected from 127.0.0.1:50002 as auto-A51C5B5B-F445-5952-5EA5-49B12F2E614D (p2, c1, k5).
1711360340: No will message specified.
1711360340: Sending CONNACK to auto-A51C5B5B-F445-5952-5EA5-49B12F2E614D (0, 0)
1711360340: Client auto-A51C5B5B-F445-5952-5EA5-49B12F2E614D disconnected: Success.
```

Is it really possible to send those large files over `mosquitto`? If so, what are the best practices regarding the implementation?

EDIT: Appending the file source code

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <mosquitto.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct mosquitto *mosq;

void publishImage(const char *topic, const char *image_path)
{
    std::ifstream fs(image_path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);  
    std::unique_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>> v_buf;
    void *msgPayload = nullptr;
    int msgPayloadLen;
    
    if (fs.good()) 
    {
        v_buf.reset(new std::vector<uint8_t>((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fs)), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>())));
        fs.close();

        msgPayload = static_cast<void*>(v_buf.get()->data());
        msgPayloadLen = v_buf.get()->size();
    }

    if(msgPayload == nullptr)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "image could not be copied to memory\n");
        return;
    }

    int rc = mosquitto_publish(mosq, NULL, topic, msgPayloadLen, msgPayload, 1, false);
    if (rc != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "mosquitto publish error: %s\n", mosquitto_strerror(rc));
    }

    return;
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough input arguments!\nUsage: imageUpdater <topic> <path_to_image>\n");
        return 1;
    }

    const char *topic = argv[1];
    const char *pathToImage = argv[2];

    mosquitto_lib_init();

    mosq = mosquitto_new(NULL, true, NULL);
    if (mosq == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Out of memory.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int rc = mosquitto_connect(mosq,  "127.0.0.1", 1883, 5);
    if (rc != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS)
    {
        mosquitto_destroy(mosq);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", mosquitto_strerror(rc));
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Connected!\n");
    }

    rc = mosquitto_loop_start(mosq);
    if (rc != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS)
    {
        mosquitto_destroy(mosq);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", mosquitto_strerror(rc));
        return 1;
    }

    publishImage(topic, pathToImage);
    mosquitto_lib_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT2: log output for a successful publish (small file)

```bash
1711376922: New client connected from 127.0.0.1:38426 as auto-33E25100-81EB-0583-E540-C73A5D29E267 (p2, c1, k5).
1711376922: No will message specified.
1711376922: Sending CONNACK to auto-33E25100-81EB-0583-E540-C73A5D29E267 (0, 0)
1711376922: Received PUBLISH from auto-33E25100-81EB-0583-E540-C73A5D29E267 (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'fota/update', ... (4192256 bytes))
1711376922: Sending PUBACK to auto-33E25100-81EB-0583-E540-C73A5D29E267 (m1, rc0)
1711376922: Client auto-33E25100-81EB-0583-E540-C73A5D29E267 closed its connection.
```

Using QOS0 instead of QOS1 makes it possible to transfer larger file, however the reliability is much lower. 10MB file transmission was successful, but only at the 5th try. Actually checking again, QOS1 also succeeded at 10MB file transmission after multiple tries. QoS0 is less reliable for the files around 4000KB than QoS1.

Comment: Split the file into chunks and reconstruct the file on the other side

Comment: That would mean sending multiple messages, right? I hoped that `mosquitto` could do that work for me instead, splitting and caring for the right order on the subscribers side is rather daunting.

Comment: MQTT was never designed to send files. It's lightweight messages for machines of very low specifications. It's the wrong tool for the job

Comment: I get that :) it's just an idea given to me by my techlead to evaluate and make a decision on further steps. The other solution is to simply sent a link to an FTP server via MQTT - something ti definitely was made for.

Comment: There is `max_packet_size` in your `mosquitto.conf` and if a client sends more than that it will be disconnected. Maybe check that.

Comment: `max_packet_size` is already set to `268435455` which IIRC is the largest possible value, the bottleneck has to be somewhere else.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78218211/edit) the question to provide a Minimal Viable Testcase based on your C code. Best guess you are not running the client event loop long enough (or at all)

Comment: And the better solution to all this is to use MQTT to send a HTTP URL to the file and have the receiver download the file. This allows for restarts if there is a problem and also is not going to block a single threaded MQTT broker like mosquitto as it tries to process this **VAST** message. (You already have a central point to host the HTTP server, on the same machine as the broker)

Comment: Edited the question, thank you for your feedback. I understand what the better approach is, the study of mqtt with large file sizes is mostly for better understanding of what's possible and gaining sufficient arguments on why is this not the right approach. Right now I'd like to understand what is the reason behind the 4MB limit.

Comment: Also add the mosquitto log output for a successful publish (small file). I suspect that `mosquitto_publish` is returning success when it has started the publish, not when it is completed. Also do things change if you use QOS 0 instead of 1 or add an arbitrary wait `publishImage` and `mosquitto_lib_cleanup`?

Comment: Thank you @hardillb, the solution was related to a pre-mature timeout.

Comment: Please do not edit answers into questions. If you have a solution, write it up as a proper answer and accept it so it will be higher in search results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct solution here is probably to use `mosquitto_loop_stop()` before `mosquitto_lib_cleanup()`

As the doc explains, this should wait for outstanding messages to be sent before exiting.

> This is part of the threaded client interface.  Call this once to stop the network thread previously created with mosquitto_loop_start.  This call will block until the network thread finishes.

Docs: https://mosquitto.org/api/files/mosquitto-h.html#mosquitto_loop_stop

Answer (score 0):

Adding the timeout before `mosquitto_lib_cleanup` was the solution. It seems that in large payload scenarios the network stack isn't able to process the whole payload before the cleanup call. Possibly the non-blocking loop (mosquitto loop was started with `mosquitto_start`) did not wait for the package to be piped into the network at all.